# Lock cells if date is current date minus two days

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel with 500 rows. i have the code that if the cells in column F have the value 500 it will lock the cells. But... if someone tries to modify something today in the last 2 rows ( that are always yesterday and the day before yesterday ) it should be able to do that. So if today is 23.02.2016 he can modify the last 2 rows but not the rest.

```
 Sub Lock_cells(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Dim cl As Range
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        For Each cl In Target.Cells
            If UCase(cl.Value) = UCase("500") And cl.Column = 6 Then
                Range("a" & cl.Row & ":f" & cl.Row).Locked = True
            Else
                Range("a" & cl.Row & ":f" & cl.Row).Locked = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Can it work if i put the sub in BeforeClose or on Open and verify if the date condition is true ? Thank you.

Comment: What is a `UCase("500")` and why is text masquerading as a number? Treating true numbers as numbers is preferential unless the column contains mixed data types. Where are the dates?

Comment: So you just need to lock every row with "500" in column D except for the last two days?

Comment: UCase("500") is from another macro that i used for the names of people in column B. And yes, i am doing some modifications in the file, save and close. tomorrow some person ads another row and i check if the added row is correct and so one for an year. But the %$#^%# remember that 1 week ago made a mistake and just modifies without letting me know.

Comment: The last 2 days also have 500 in D column but i must keep them open for the @#$@#$ who forget something .

Comment: The dates are in column A - always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to find the last row and then unlock the last two rows by offset.

```
Dim LastRow As Range

Set LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Range(LastRow, LastRow.Offset(-1, -5)).Locked = False
Set LastRow = Nothing
```

EDIT:
If you want rows to be unlocked based on dates in column A then you should modify your `If` condition to compare dates

```
If UCase(cl.Value) = UCase("500") And cl.offset(0,-5).value < Today() - 2 Then
    Range("a" & cl.Row & ":f" & cl.Row).Locked = True
Else
    Range("a" & cl.Row & ":f" & cl.Row).Locked = False
End If
```

No need to check for column = 6 since you enter the outer `If` only if target = 6

Comment: thank you for your answer but find lastrow unlocks rows 499 and 500 because from A4 To A500 are the dates of the year - in order but can be duplicated : A38 to A90 has 19.01.2016 as date.

Comment: I thought that is what you intend do as you said the last two rows should be open for modification. so if your data is from A4 to A550 in future than Row 549 and 550 will be open

Comment: The D column has value 0 from the last modified row to row 500. Today the last row with value 500 is  row 121 . from 122 to 500 the value is 0 .

Comment: I edited the answer to check against date. If that doesn't work, i would like to understand your question more clearly. Maybe a sample datasheet will help

Comment: It did the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone interested i made the code to check if the day is a working day ( a 5 days working week  that starts with Monday ) and will keep the last 2 days modifiable (unlocked). The file has 499 rows. So in the first column are the dates, columns 2,3,4,5 have characters and in the column F (column 6) is the value 500 or 0. The macro will check if the value from column F is 500 and if is true will block the row. Furthermore the macro will check if the value with 500 will have a work day as corespondent and if is true it will block the row but if the value 500 is in week-end it will remain modifiable (unlocked). Thank you [PankajR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3099567/pankajr) for the help.

`Sub Lock_cells()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim x As Date
  x = Now() - 3
 ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
 Dim cl As Range
 Set rng = Range("F3:F499")

    For Each cl In rng.Cells

        If UCase(cl.Value) = UCase("500") And cl.Offset(0, -5).Value < x Then

              If Weekday(cl.Offset(0, -5).Value, vbMonday) < 6 Then

                     Range("a" & cl.Row & ":F" & cl.Row).Locked = True
                    Else
                     Range("a" & cl.Row & ":F" & cl.Row).Locked = False
              End If

        End If

    Next

    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"

End Sub`